# Select value from array of objects Cosmos DB

Tags: json, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have the following json

```
{
"car-id": "54-38ncv",
"cars": [
{
"name": "Ferrari",
"horse-powers": 400
},
{
"name": "BMW",
"horse-powers": 200
},
{
"name": "Audi",
"horse-powers": 145
}]
}
```

the id is custom set by me. Imagine that there are hundreds other documents in my azure cosmos db collection. I want to create query that selects the first document that has a car in the cars that is named etc. "Ferrari". I know that they are maybe a dublicates, but is want the first one. Is there a quarry for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this,

```
SELECT TOP 1 FROM c JOIN cc IN c.cars WHERE cc.name IN ("Ferrari")
```

Comment: Great. I was overcomplicating the solution!

Comment: mark if the answer helped